# Xamarin iOS : SSO using SAML

Tags: xamarin, oauth, xamarin.ios, saml, saml-2.0

I am trying to implement SSO feature on to my app (XAMARIN iOS App). Here is the login flow. User enters Customer ID and submits it. If the Customer ID has SSO setup , it will pop up a web view and loads a site to enter login parameters (Username, Password). Once user is authenticated, it returns a SAML token.

1.)How to capture this SAML token ?

2.)Is OAuth authentication different from SAML authentication ? Please explain.

3.)I have tried using OAuth but its not working. Can any explain me Step by Step procedure on how to implement this type of Authentication ??

Comment: Hi Bharat!, Asking someone to explain a "step by step" procedure for you isn't the best kind of question to ask here. A better question would be to post what you already have tried and ask people to help you with a specific problem.

Comment: I recommend you use Xamarin.Auth this component helps you to make an SSO in your Xamarin app.https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Auth/